# C4 option has disappeared in XCODE after upgrade

Tags: c4

The C4 option for an application has disappeared. Does XCODE do background updating? Can I turn this off? It seems to have effected C4, is this correct?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just upgraded from 4.5 to 4.6 it may be that you simply have to reinstall.

I haven't upgraded yet, but I assume this will fix the problem because Xcode is an app and when it installs it removes the old one and replaces it with a new one. The template files are installed directly into the app, and not a shared place external to Xcode (which is why the files get deleted).

Also, I'm not sure about the background updating.